# Sum of finite series given sum of cubes

Tags: summation

The question says -
If $1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots+10^3=3025$, then what is the value of the following series which is ?

$$4+32+108+\cdots+4000$$

Comment: Hint:$$4=4\times1^3\\32=4\times2^3\\108=4\times3^3\\\vdots$$

Answer (score 4):

Answer is $12100$

Solution $-$
\begin{eqnarray*}
4 + 32 + 108 + \cdots + 4000 &=& 4 (1 + 8 + 27 + ….. 1000) \\
&=& 4 (1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + \cdots + 10^3 )\\
&=& 4 \times 3025 = \color{blue}{12100} \ (\text{Answer}) 
\end{eqnarray*}
Go to http://jobsandhan.com/mcq-questions-answers/arithmetic-aptitude/ Question No $11$ and check solution

Comment: Great first answer. $\ddot \smile$